# Pine Script Bar Index Condition for a Function

Tags: function, for-loop, pine-script, pine-script-v5

The function checks the wavetrend cross and is displayed if the condition is met. I want the function to run for every bar within the last 5 bars. How can I do it with Bar Index

```
func_wave() =>
n1 = input(10, 'Channel Length')
n2 = input(21, 'Average Length')
obLevel1 = input(60, 'Over Bought Level 1')
obLevel2 = input(53, 'Over Bought Level 2')
osLevel1 = input(-60, 'Over Sold Level 1')
osLevel2 = input(-53, 'Over Sold Level 2')
ap = hlc3
esa = ta.ema(ap, n1)
d = ta.ema(math.abs(ap - esa), n1)
ci = (ap - esa) / (0.015 * d)
tci = ta.ema(ci, n2)

wt1 = tci
wt2 = ta.sma(wt1, 4)

con = ta.crossover(wt1, wt2) 
con

s1 = request.security('BTCUSDT', timeframe.period, func_wave())
s2 = request.security('ETHUSDT', timeframe.period, func_wave())
s3 = request.security('BNBUSDT', timeframe.period, func_wave())
scr_label = 'WT\n' 
scr_label := s1 ? scr_label + 'BTCUSDT\n' : scr_label
scr_label := s2 ? scr_label + 'ETHUSDT\n' : scr_label
scr_label := s3 ? scr_label + 'BNBUSDT\n' : scr_label

I = label.new(bar_index -165, 0, scr_label, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, 
style=label.style_label_up, yloc=yloc.price)
label.delete(I[1])
plot(0, color=color.new(color.white, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ta.barssince function
[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta{dot}barssince](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dbarssince)

Comment: Thanks for answer. How can i execute the rule if this condition is met only in the last 5 bars

Comment: Solved. Thaks again con = ta.crossover(wt1, wt2) 
    since_con_crossover = ta.barssince(sart01)
    buy = since_sart01_crossover <= 5
    buy